# How can I Encrypt Video in Real Time?

Tags: encryption, video

I'm looking for a, preferably open source, library or program to encrypt video in real time for security purposes, not DRM. I've found several decent algorithms, RVEA and VEA, but before I try hacking together an implementation I wanted to see if one already existed or if there was a better way of doing this since these methods are a little old.

Comment: Interesting question. Any reason you can't serve it over HTTPS?

Comment: You could use any stream cypher?

Comment: @silky, HTTPS has a few drawbacks. Encryption is done during serving rather than in advance and stored, so you need more CPU on the edge than you otherwise would.  Also, since it's re-encrypted per-user it's not cacheable (at the CDN, at the ISP, and in the browser).

Comment: Ry4an: Fair enough. But how do you plan on doing the decryption then? Or do you have a custom client-side player? If it's custom-client side, seems you could encrypt with whatever you want.

Comment: Nice try ;)  http://news.cnet.com/8301-1009_3-10417247-83.html

Comment: @silky, yeah, unless you're matching the IETF draft to which I link in my answer closely (in which case there are a few clients that'll already do the decrypt) you'll need some software on the client side.  It doesn't have to be the player though, a HTTP proxy could do it. I was figuring that Colin was writing new client software, but if he's not he's limited to the craptacular DRM system built in whichever player he picks.

Comment: Actually, streaming would probably be the easier part. What I'm looking for is a way to save video from a camera in an encrypted format as it's recording.

The idea behind RVEA is to use an arbitrary encryption algorithm to control only when signed bits in a video are flipped. Changing just those signed bits is enough to make it extremely difficult to tell what's going on in the video, and it's computationally inexpensive. I just wanted to know if there was a better way or a current implementation.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest used AES-128 in counted block (not the usual chained block) mode.  It's easily done using openssl, and it's available in hardware on most all mobile and CE devices, so those become options should you had that way in the future.

One place it's used is in the chunked HTTP streaming from apple per this spec: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-02

Answer (score 2):

You are a little vague on the requirements, but if you are simply looking for a very fast method of encrypting a stream of data, then RC4 is still not a bad way to go. It is extremely fast; I think it will be faster than any credible block cipher. And you can use an arbitrarily long key.

There seems to be quite a bit of talk about RC4 being "old" and needing to be replaced, but I do not think there are any published breaks of it.  Of course, if I were the bad guy who broke it, I probably would keep that bit of information close to my chest and use it for a bit of old-fashioned thieving. So who really knows. The primary issue that I *think* is published is that you should cycle the s-box for some number of iterations before using the keystream. A pdf describing that statistical weakness is available [here](http://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/publications/article-40.pdf).

And this algorithm is available in [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), which also meets your requirements.  I honestly can't say how any of this relates to RVEA; I know nothing about it.  A very quick google search turns up mostly hits that require logins to learn about it.  Although, one opaque reference seemed to imply that RVEA can use any number of ciphers.  Maybe it already supports RC4.